# Unable to save into core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have 2 ViewControllers connected to Tab Bar Controller. One ViewController should show table data from core data, another one has two inputs text fields and enter button to save input data to core data. However, I am not able to save using 'var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?'. I am not using any segues to pass data. Do I code correctly?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddNameViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Properties

@IBOutlet var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var lastNameTextField: UITextField!

var person: Person?
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Add Name"

}

// MARK: - Actions

@IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }

    if person == nil {
        let newName = Person(context: managedObjectContext)

        newName.firstName = firstNameTextField.text
        newName.lastName = lastNameTextField.text
        newName.createdAt = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

    }
    try? managedObjectContext.save()
}
```

}

I probably mislead everyone. Here is my table view code. And I do not have boilerplate in AppDelegate.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

// MARK: - Persistent Container

private let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "People")

// MARK: - Fetch results controller

fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController:      NSFetchedResultsController<Person> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Person.createdAt), ascending: true
        )]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Person.lastName), cacheName: nil)

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "People"

    persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (persistentSoreDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to load persistent store")
            print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.setupView()

            do {
                try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            } catch {
                let fetchError = error as NSError
                print("Unable to perform fetch request")
                print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
            }

            self.updateView()
        }
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
}

// MARK: - Views

private func setupView() {
    setupMessageLabel()

    updateView()
}

fileprivate func updateView() {
    var hasNames = false

    if let people = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
        hasNames = people.count > 0
    }

    tableView.isHidden = !hasNames
    messageLabel.isHidden = hasNames

    activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
}

private func setupMessageLabel() {
    messageLabel.text = "You do not have names yet."
}

// MARK: - Notification handling

@objc func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ notification: Notification) {
    do {
        try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to save changes")
        print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

}

```
extension ViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()

    updateView()
}

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch (type) {
    case .insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break
    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break
    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PersonTableViewCell {
            configure(cell, at: indexPath)
        }
    default:
        break

    }
}

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

```
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections  else { return 0 }
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else { fatalError("Unexpected section") }
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    guard let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else { fatalError("Unexpected section") }
    return sectionInfo.name
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PersonTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PersonTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Unexpected indexPath")
    }

    // Configure cell
    configure(cell, at: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func configure(_ cell: PersonTableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let name = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

    // Configure cell
    cell.firstNameLabel.text = name.firstName
    cell.lastNameLabel.text = name.lastName
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let name = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        name.managedObjectContext?.delete(name)
    }
}
```

}

```
extension ViewController: UITabBarDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

}

Comment: you are not notifying the table after the data is saved, try reloading table.

Comment: Where do you set the `managedObjectContext` variable?

Comment: I posted the rest of my code.

Comment: is this query solved ?

Comment: Yes, it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to insert New Record you are trying to save as below

```
//Create Reference for New AudioFile
let newPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: context) as! Person

//Set Values
newPerson.fileName = firstNameTextField.text
newPerson.lastName = lastNameTextField.text
newPerson.craetedAt = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

//Save Context here
self.saveChanges() 


//MARK:- Saves all changes
func saveChanges()
{
  do{
       try context.save()
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
       // failure
       print(error)
    }
}
```

Also I will recommend you to check a working code related to core data

Github Link - https://github.com/RockinGarg/CoreData_Swift_Demo.git

This project works to save, fetch, Delete By ID, delete Entity Data and Predicate using a separate core Class (NSObject Class)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `NSPersistentContainer` reference? You have to initialize your CoreData stack first using the aforesaid container and then try saving context on that.

Try the following:

1. Declare your NSPersistentContainer reference.

   ```
   var container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer
   ```
2. Use the container's backgroundtask queue for saving the context.

   ```
   container?.performBackgroundTask{ _ in
       guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }

       if person == nil {
           let newName = Person(context: managedObjectContext)

           newName.firstName = firstNameTextField.text
           ...

       }

       try? managedObjectContext.save() 
   }
   ```

Have a look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1) for detail.

3. I am assuming the boilerplate persistentContainer code is something you'd have in AppDelegate already given you are using CoreData, i.e.,

   ```
   lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

       let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "myModel")
       container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
           if let error = error as NSError? {
               fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
           }
       })
       return container
   }()
   ```

Comment: Don't declare `container` as optional. The container is required to exist as well as `AppDelegate`. If `AppDelegate` was missing the app won't even launch.  Force cast AppDelegate `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer`

Comment: I understand your point. However, Apple doesn't vouch for the persistentContainer property to be always reliable. They recommend to use optionals for referring to it. `This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.`

Comment: Additionally, Swift has optionals to use such opportunity for error handling. Hence, I do not prefer forced unwrap. Despite saying so, your method would work fine as well.